# @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL does not work for double

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I am trying to retrieve `{"status":201}` in the case of `route!=0` but I am getting `{"status":201,"distance":0.0}` how can I reach that with `@JsonInclude` or Jackson also without `"distance":0.0`?

```
SDBean bean = new SDBean();
if (routeD != 0) {
    // Insert the data into the bus table
    bean.status = db.insertData(macD, routeD, latD, longD);

    return Response.status(bean.status).entity(bean.toJson()).build();

}
```

SDBean class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class SDBean {

    public int status;
    public ArrayList<Integer> routes;
    public double distance;

    public SDBean(){
    status = 230;
}

    public String toJson() {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = null;
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
         System.out.println(json);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your Json object?

Comment: @JordiCastilla: what do you mena with json object? I do not have once everything is being created by the jackson libraray?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Double`. primitives (`double`) can't be null (they have default values)

Comment: Or maybe `OptionalDouble` to make the intent clear? (although you need to register the Jdk8Module too)